# I made my partition too small

Tags: 13.10

I made a partition to install (20gig) and I'm realizing it's too small. Do I need to reformat and start over or is there a fix to this as I've already been using and love it. I hate to have to do over what Ive done but will if thats the best answer.
Windows 7 64bit

Comment: It is the partition for Ubuntu or Windows ?
also can you show a screenshot of your Partition from Gparted or from other ubuntu partitioning software ?

Answer (score 0):

20 gig is more sufficient for an Ubuntu installation.  If you need more space for a directory like `/home`, `/opt`, `/srv` or `/var`, you can move these to a new partition and mount it over the directory.

If you need more space for a Windows partion, you may be able to use a tool like `partionmanager` to resize the partition.  You will need to install the package before using it.  However, if you have a failed installation, you may want to delete and recreate the partition with the proper size.

EDIT: There are lots of guides to adding a new partition to linux such as [this one](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/add_new_partitions_to_an_existing_system).  Moving `/var` is likely the best bet to move first.

The command `apt-get clean` should free up a fair bit of space fairly quickly.  It will remove the file used to install the packages.   Often `apt-get autoclean` will free up a fair bit of space by removing outdated package downloads.

Comment: This sounds like something I can do. Could you help a little as I don't know how to configure. I have a 500gig hard drive and I can make another partition to use but I'm really unfamiliar as to how to direct to another drive. I've added updates and added a few programs ie. email prog. and office prog off thier site so I only have about a gig left.

Comment: @Cyrus Adding new partitions has been documented elsewhere.  From the description partitionmanager may be able to do the move for you.  gparted is another solution, although I prefer to have multiple partitions.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use [Gparted](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted/) to resize your Partition. You can install it on Ubuntu from the

Software-Center. You can also download it to use it like a [LiveCD](http://gparted.org/download.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can probably resize the partition but it depends on a lot of things you haven't mentions

1) Is there free space on the drive?

2) What format is the partition in?
(Some filesystems such as btrfs & reiszerfs support online resizing)

3) Where is the free space relative to the linux partition?
(If you need to move a partition in use partition you will need to use a liveCD)

4) Are you using LVM?
(If you are you can add a Physical Volume that is not connected to the existing space and use it to expand logical volumes without having to use a liveCD)

Your best plan is to

1. Install Gparted
2. Use Gparted to figure out the answer to the above questions
3. Write out a plan of actions on paper so you can follow it through across reboots and liveCDs
4. Take a backup of anything important
5. (If needed) Download a gparted ISO from http://gparted.org/livecd.php
6. Use Gparted (either liveCD or on your install) to rearrange your disk